# How to create directory exceeding MAX_PATH

Tags: c#, windows, max-path

For testing purpose, I would like to create on disk a directory which exceeds the Windows MAX_PATH limit.
How can I do that?

(I tried Powershell, cmd, windows explorer => it's blocked.)

**Edited:**
The use of ZlpIOHelper from ZetaLongPaths library allows to do that whereas the standard Directory class throws the dreaded exception:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = @"d:\temp\";
        var dirName = "LooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooongSubDirectory";
        while (path.Length <= 280)
        {
            path = Path.Combine(path, dirName);
            ZlpIOHelper.CreateDirectory(path); //Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(path);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: In C# try this library: http://zetalongpaths.codeplex.com/....or if it's in WIN32 then you need to use the special prefix to allow for longer file names. see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx

Comment: There's a comment in some of the API methods that you can use "\\?\" with the Unicode calls as a prefix for long paths, but I don't know if that translates into command-line tools

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In WIN32 you need to use the special "\\?\" prefix to allow for longer file names.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx

> For file I/O, the "\\?\" prefix to a path string tells the Windows
>   APIs to disable all string parsing and to send the string that follows
>   it straight to the file system. For example, if the file system
>   supports large paths and file names, you can exceed the MAX_PATH
>   limits that are otherwise enforced by the Windows APIs. For more
>   information about the normal maximum path limitation, see the previous
>   section Maximum Path Length Limitation.

As you are using C# then try this library which will save you having to do all the PInvokes to the WIN32 file API and adding the prefix to the paths.

- http://zetalongpaths.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to create a directory `c:\A\averylongnamethatgoesonandonandon...`,
and then rename `C:\A` to something much longer. Windows does not check every child of A to see if the name of that child would exceed `MAX_PATH`.

Comment: You wouldn't rename an existing directory to a short name, then create a long sub-directory and then rename it back. No, not a good solution. Also, you can't do that if files of `A` are in use.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
var path = "C:\\";
while (path.Length <= 260)
{
    path = Path.Combine(path, "Another Sub Directory");
}
```

Comment: darn it, you beat me to it +1

Comment: I assumed he meant "create on disk"?

Comment: Just add the create dir from my comment and there you have it

Comment: @Rup: yes. I edited the question@Sayse: you get the PathTooLongException

Comment: @sthiers - But I'm pretty sure you will have created the directory up until that point